# How to create button with background white and no border, only a bottom line under the text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been searching for solution but cannot find.

I want a button with no border but with text with a bottom line (it looks like a link button in Web).

Below is the button and I have tries below attributes :

```
android:style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
android:style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle
android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" 
android:style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"



<Button            
android:id="@+id/ForgetPwd"            
android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
android:layout_margin="10dp"            
android:background="#7AD8D3"            
android:text="Forget password"  

android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"    

android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flat button from material design to get a borderless button.

http://www.materialdoc.com/flat-button/

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ForgetPwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Forgot Password?"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

I don't think you can get underline on a button text with just xml. You can achieve it using the below code

```
Button forgetPwdButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ForgetPwd);
forgetPwdButton.PaintFlags = forgetPwdButton.PaintFlags | Android.Graphics.PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
```

[image]

Comment: I place this : style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" in the Button XML, I go this ErrMsg: the style attribute is not declared

Comment: Add Xamarin.Android.Aupport.V7.Appcompat package to your project via nuget and rebuild.

Comment: I add this android:background="#ffffff" and take away style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" and use your code to draw the underline. It works this way. As for the style, is this @style/widget is a built-in? it seems Xamarin not recognize it.

Comment: also why the letters all in capital even i used this text: android:text="Forgot Password"